# UITextView when put in a UITableViewCell sometimes do not display the content

Tags: cocoa-touch

I wonder if anyone else is facing the same issue. I have a UITextView field placed in a UITableViewCell. Sometimes it does not displays the text. When i click or scroll the table view, it appears. Any guesses?

---

Details:

I call a method in *viewDidLoad* method that calls a web service to retrieve some data. On receiving the data, i set the values of *UILabel* and *UITextView*. *UILabel* values appear fine, but the *UITextView* (sometimes) do not show the value until i move to subview or scroll up and down to revisit the area contaning *UITextView*. I'm showing *UILabel* and *UITextView* objects in *UITableViewCell*. I call *[tableView reloadData]* right after setting values in *UILabel* and *UITextView*, but i do not re-create the *UITableViewCell*.

Thanks for your reply and pointers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this by calling `[myTableView reloadData];`

Answer (score 3):

I had this same problem more or less - a UITextView inside a custom UITableViewCell subclass would not display its text until you touched (and thus scrolled) the UITextView. This would only happen with the FIRST cell in the table. I couldn't figure out why it was happening, but the problem was easily fixed by just "nudging" the UITextView's contentOffset programmatically.

```
problemCell.textView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0.0, 1.0);
problemCell.textView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0.0, 0.0);
```

Comment: this helped me too, though I had a textview NOT in a cell, but in a view that was resized after viewDidLoad (pop-over on iPad that animated taller after coming in on a nav controller).  Adding the contentOffset calls in viewDidAppear fixed the invisible-text-until-scrolled bug for me.

Answer (score 1):

This might have something to do with the fact that UITextView and UITableView are both subclasses of UIScrollView. So you have a scroll view inside of a scroll view, and it wouldn't surprise me if that was the cause of your problems.

If you don't need to edit the text within the table, just use a multi-line UILabel.

If you absolutely have to have a UITextView inside a UITableView, perhaps disabling scrolling on one of them might also fix the problem. (I think the property name is `scrollEnabled` or `scrollingEnabled`.)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you're calling `[super viewWillAppear:]` and `[super viewDidAppear:]` in all the places where you override viewWillAppear or viewDidAppear.

Probably true of all the other viewDidWhatever and viewWillWhatever methods as well.

The problem you're having suggests that the UITextView isn't getting the message to draw itself on the screen when you're first displaying the table but does get the message when it needs to refresh.